# How to store/retrieve SCNNode position?

Tags: position, store, scenekit

How to store and retrieve SceneKit SCNNode position ?

Any Objective C code example ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SCNNode position is an SCNVector3

```
// Storing the position of myNode node into nodePosition variable
SCNVector3 nodePosition = myNode.position;
```

However, if there is an animation or physics simulation playing `.position` properties of the nodes involved are not updated.

Instead, you should read `.presentationNode` property for the current position:

```
// Getting the current position of myNode
// if an animation or physics simulation is in progress
SCNVector3 nodePosition = myNode.presentationNode.position;
```